# Reading from Lists in Python

Tags: python, list

I want to access the scores associated with each letter of the alphabet which are stored in a text file (stores.txt). Each line is an index and I just want to retrieve the number for each letter and print it when I enter a certain letter into a function. How would I split the item in order to get the number and return it.

```
Scores.txt is shown like this: 
A 1
B 3
C 5
D 3
E 1
F 5
G 4
H 3 
I 1
J 10
K 8
L 3
M 5
N 3
O 2
P 5
Q 20
R 3
S 3
T 2
U 1
V 10
W 12
X 16
Y 8
Z 20

This is the code ive used up to now, however this would result in displaying the whole line 
(['A','1']) when i passed A to the function and I would like just 1 to be passed.

def getLetterScore(user_Input):
scoreFileT1 = open('D:/DELL/Desktop/Programming Assignment/scores.txt')
score = []
for line in scoreFileT1:
        line = line.strip(' ')
        line = line.split()
        score.append(line)
scoreFileT1.close()
if user_Input =='a' or user_Input == 'A':
    print(score[0])
```

Comment: Please adhere to StackOverflow guidelines. This site is not for seeking answers for your programming assignment!

Comment: Since this seems to be a homework question I will just give you pointers, not a direct answer. Hope this is even more helpful for you in the long run: 1) the line.split() operation creates a tuple. Ask yourself: how to unpack that tuple? Or: How to access a specific element of a tuple 2) you used a list for the score variable. I recommend a dict instead. Ask yourself: Why is this the far better option? 3) in general open files using "with" instead of open()...close()

Comment: Additional remark: 4) simplify your code regarding those checks for "a" and "A" by using upper() or lower() methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code I came up with.
In this, if you give any letter as input, the corresponding number for the letter will be printed.

```
def getLetterScore(user_Input):
    scoreFileT1 = open('C://Users//Naveendran//Desktop//scores.txt')
    score = []
    for line in scoreFileT1:
        line = line.strip(' ')
        line = line.split()
        score.append(line)
    scoreFileT1.close()
    for i in range(len(score)):
        if user_Input.upper() == score[i][0]: 
            print(score[i][1])
        

b = input("Enter a letter:")
getLetterScore(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you going with this code

```
rfile=open("score.txt")   #add your path here
file=rfile.read()
filesplit=file.split("\n")
letter=input("enter The number").capitalize()
for i in filesplit:
    if(i[0]==letter):
        for j in range(2,len(i)):
            print(i[j],end="")
```